# out of memory formatting.php line 4651

Tags: php, memory, out

I got Wordpress with Elementor Pro and for some reason always get 500 Server Errors when trying to save the page. It is not a large page, however these errors constantly occour. And i am getting really desperated...

I already changed the theme to twentyseventeen to make sure it is not due to the theme.
the error log shows:

> [19-May-2018 08:00:56 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 192937984) (tried to allocate 782336 bytes) in /mnt/web322/c1/96/59163196/htdocs/WordPress_01/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4651

First I checked the memory limit in my wp-config, which seems to be alright:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' );
```

My webhost is Strato who has 128M.

The relevant lines of my formatting.php can be found here. I am not sure whether the linenumbers are 100% correct, i just used an online tool that started first line with 1.

```
4640/**
4641 * Normalize EOL characters and strip duplicate whitespace.
4642 *
4643 * @since 2.7.0
4644 *
4645 * @param string $str The string to normalize.
4646 * @return string The normalized string.
4647 */
4648function normalize_whitespace( $str ) {
4649    $str  = trim( $str );
4650    $str  = str_replace( "\r", "\n", $str );
4651    $str  = preg_replace( array( '/\n+/', '/[ \t]+/' ), array( "\n", ' ' ), $str );
4652    return $str;
4653}
4654
```

Do you have any idea?
I would be more than thankful!
Best,
DJT